# Compiling C++ library to wasm using clang failed with 'stdlib.h' file not found error

Tags: c, rust, clang, wasm-pack, webassembly

I'm trying to compile [this example](https://github.com/outersky/simple_excel_writer) code from rust to wasm. It's a rust crate that lets you create/write excel files. I've successfully managed to run it using `cargo run`.

Unfortunately, when I try to compile it to web assembly I'm experiencing an error which states that the library `<stdlib.h>`, a common C library, cannot be found while compiling [bzip2-sys](https://github.com/alexcrichton/bzip2-rs), a rust crate.

When I first tried to compile it, it prompted me to install clang which I did from [here](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html) (pre-built binary for Windows (64-bit and 32-bit)) and I've included `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin` to the system Path environment variable. I also have MinGW-w64 installed, as well as Visual Studio 2017 with Visual C++ build tools.

You can see the whole error generated in Visual Studio Code below.

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\excel-test> wasm-pack build
[INFO]: Checking for the Wasm target...
[INFO]: Compiling to Wasm...
   Compiling libc v0.2.71
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.17
   Compiling cc v1.0.54
   Compiling crc32fast v1.2.0
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling adler32 v1.0.4
   Compiling podio v0.1.7
   Compiling miniz_oxide v0.3.6
   Compiling time v0.1.43
   Compiling flate2 v1.0.14
   Compiling bzip2-sys v0.1.9+1.0.8
error: failed to run custom build command for `bzip2-sys v0.1.9+1.0.8`

Caused by:
  process didnt exit successfully: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\excel-test\target\release\build\bzip2-sys-aa88969feaab6a44\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stdout
TARGET = Some("wasm32-unknown-unknown")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
TARGET_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
TARGET_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
DEBUG = Some("false")
running: "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\excel-test\\target\\wasm32-unknown-unknown\\release\\build\\bzip2-sys-03c492d40657ce9f\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" "bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c"
cargo:warning=In file included from bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c:22:
cargo:warning=bzip2-1.0.8/bzlib_private.h:25:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
cargo:warning=#include <stdlib.h>
cargo:warning=         ^~~~~~~~~~
cargo:warning=1 error generated.
exit code: 1

--- stderr


error occurred: Command "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\excel-test\\target\\wasm32-unknown-unknown\\release\\build\\bzip2-sys-03c492d40657ce9f\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" "bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c" with args "clang" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).



Error: Compiling your crate to WebAssembly failed
Caused by: failed to execute `cargo build`: exited with exit code: 101
  full command: "cargo" "build" "--lib" "--release" "--target" "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\excel-test>
```

Comment: If you're a Rust user and got here due to failing to compile the `zip` crate with `wasm-pack`, [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/zip-rs/zip/issues/113) indicates that a potential solution is to set `default-features = false` in the `zip` dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the file is is some dir, you may have to help clang find it:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#include-path-management

Flags controlling how #includes are resolved to files.

-I, --include-directory , --include-directory=